# Dual monitors - only one is working, and it keeps going black for a few seconds

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I have two monitors for my desktop pc, and it's worked for years. Yesterday I went to display settings and chose "Single display". When trying to come back to "Join displays", everything went wrong.

Now only my primary monitor is working, but it is only turned on for about 5 seconds, then it goes black for 3 seconds. This goes on in an endless loop.

When I try to change display settings to "Join displays", it simply doesn't apply the change. Only by unplugging the secondary monitor, I am able to use my pc now without the primary monitor going black every 5 second.

When both monitors are plugged, I am able to do ctrl + alt + F5 and in tty5, both monitors are working, and no blinking is occurring. I can also boot to win10 without any problems.

Primary monitor is DisplayPort (144hz)
Secondary is HDMI (60hz)

Ubuntu 22.04

kernel 5.15.10-051510-generic

GNOME Version 42.2

GPU AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.1.0-devel (git-eaf3c72 2022-03-25 impish-oibaf-ppa)